# Linked list head is pointing to third node after a bubble sort. The list inside function is correct but when printing in main, list is shorter

Tags: c

This is for a programming assignment where we have to sort a single linked list by 'id'. We are given function prototypes that cannot be changed. In my 'sortEmployee' function, the list is sorted correctly when I print inside the function but when I try to print the original list inside main after sorting, the list is shorter. I believe the head is somehow is being pointed elsewhere in the function.

I'm not allowed to change the function prototype. The prof wants us to print the sorted list from inside the function without modifying the linked list in the main that is passed through the sortEmployee() function. So the linked list should be the same as after sorting.

I've been banging my head at this function for so long I'm exhausted.

```
struct employee     // linked list structure
{
   char fname[MAX_LENGTH];
   char lname[MAX_LENGTH];
   int empId;              
   int numDependents;
   char  ** dependents;
   struct employee * nextEmployee;          
};
```

```
void sortEmployee (struct employee * head){     // sorting function

    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Error!\n");
        return;
    }

    a3Emp * current, *sorted, *previous;
    a3Emp * newHead = head;

    int swapped = 1;

    while(swapped) {
        swapped = 0;
        previous = NULL;
        current= newHead;

        while(current->nextEmployee != NULL) {
            sorted = current->nextEmployee;
            if(current->empId > sorted->empId) {
                current->nextEmployee = sorted->nextEmployee;
                sorted->nextEmployee = current;
                if(previous == NULL) {
                    newHead= sorted;
                } else {
                    previous->nextEmployee = sorted;
                }
                previous = sorted;
                swapped = 1;
            } else {
                previous= current;
                current = current->nextEmployee;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Employees sorted by Employee Id: \n");
    printLL(newHead);

}


void printLL (struct employee * head){    // print function

    a3Emp *newTemp = head;                   

    int count = 0;

    if(newTemp == NULL){
        printf("List not found! Please try again\n");
    }


    while(newTemp != NULL){                    

        printf("\nEmployee #%d: \n", count + 1 );

        printf("\tEmployee id: %d\n", newTemp ->empId);
        printf("\tFirst Name: %s\n", newTemp ->fname);
        printf("\tLast Name: %s\n", newTemp ->lname);

        printf("\tDependents: ");

        int i = 0;
        if(newTemp ->numDependents == 0){
                printf("N/A \n");
            } else {

            while(i < newTemp ->numDependents){

                if(i == newTemp ->numDependents - 1){
                    printf("%s\n", newTemp ->dependents[i]);
                } else {
                    printf("%s, ", newTemp ->dependents[i]);
                }

                i++;

            }
        }


        newTemp = newTemp ->nextEmployee;              

        count++;

    }

    printf("There are currently %d employees.\n", count);

}
```

When I call printLL(head) in main this is what I get:

```
Employee #1:
        Employee id: 402
        First Name: Eugene
        Last Name: Martin
        Dependents: Exe, Why

Employee #2:
        Employee id: 809
        First Name: Sania
        Last Name: Mirza
        Dependents: Bee, Kay

Employee #3:
        Employee id: 106
        First Name: Andre
        Last Name: Sampras
        Dependents: Ef, Zed

Employee #4:
        Employee id: 100
        First Name: Roger
        Last Name: Nadal
        Dependents: Eye, Jee

Employee #5:
        Employee id: 524
        First Name: Johnny
        Last Name: Boy
        Dependents: kid, kidster
```

When I call sortEmployee(head) in main, the output is as follows:

```
Employee #1:
        Employee id: 100
        First Name: Roger
        Last Name: Nadal
        Dependents: Eye, Jee

Employee #2:
        Employee id: 106
        First Name: Andre
        Last Name: Sampras
        Dependents: Ef, Zed

Employee #3:
        Employee id: 402
        First Name: Eugene
        Last Name: Martin
        Dependents: Exe, Why

Employee #4:
        Employee id: 524
        First Name: Johnny
        Last Name: Boy
        Dependents: kid, kidster

Employee #5:
        Employee id: 809
        First Name: Sania
        Last Name: Mirza
        Dependents: Bee, Kay
```

But when I call printLL(head) in main after calling sortEmployee(head), the output becomes:

```
Employee #1:
        Employee id: 402
        First Name: Eugene
        Last Name: Martin
        Dependents: Exe, Why

Employee #2:
        Employee id: 524
        First Name: Johnny
        Last Name: Boy
        Dependents: kid, kidster

Employee #3:
        Employee id: 809
        First Name: Sania
        Last Name: Mirza
        Dependents: Bee, Kay
```

The output should be the same as when I called printLL(head) the first time. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: You typically have a new head node after the list is sorted, but you've no way to tell the calling code which node is the new head node.  You should probably change the function signature to `struct employee *sortEmployee(struct employee *head)` — or, less tastefully (IMO), to `void sortEmployee(struct employee **phead)`.  In either case, you have to change the call to the function and the internals of the function.  The internal changes are easier when you return the new head pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your response, unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the function signature. The prof wants us to print the sorted list from inside the function without modifying the linked list that is passed through the sortEmployee() function.

Comment: Have you considered making an array of pointers to each of the LL nodes, sorting and printing by using those pointers within your function, leaving the LL members absolutely alone? Seems a simple solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _Side note:_ I also dislike the `**phead` parameter. I prefer a list struct: `struct list { struct employee *head; struct employee *tail; };` and to change the first arg to: `struct list *list` Then, _all_ functions just receive that pointer. Those that need to change `head/tail` can do so. But, now, the _caller_ does _not_ have to know _which_ functions will change `head` or not. It also lays the groundwork for changing the singly linked list into a doubly linked one with minimal overhead/change.

Comment: @unmasked_crusader It may have some pedagogic purpose, but after sorting, _if_ the `head` is changed, there is no way for a _caller_ of `sortEmployee` to know/receive this. So, after the call, the list is [effectively] _destroyed_. So, _not_ being able to have the prototype of `sortEmployee` return the updated `head` value is bad design [by the instructor] ...

Comment: @CraigEstey
I think the point is to challenge the student to develop the solution proposed by Rust (@Fe2O3).

Comment: @unmasked_crusader ... Unless, the `head` node is a _dummy_ node that functions like the `list` struct I mentioned to Jonathan (where `head->next` is like `list->head`).

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you! Your solution worked! I now understand that having the prototype as it is the linked list will be effectively be changed for good. The array of pointers did exactly what I wanted it to.

Comment: @CraigEstey I agree with "bad design"... For a trivial node holding an `int` or `double`, who cares... Here, the payload is large and more complex, and, imho, should be held apart from the LL data structure requirements...

Comment: Glad you had success... I didn't mention it, but the "guts" of printing the fields should be factored out to its own function separate from the traversal... Hoping you did this so that you can print using one function from either a LL or an array... Keep on learning.. :-)

Comment: @Motomotes That's possible. But, at this stage for OP, I'd say if the instructor wanted that they should put that into the problem description. Otherwise, my dummy node is a possibility. One of the main points of a linked list with N nodes is to _not_ require a linear array of length N. Since Fe2O3's solution has fixed OP's issue, this may be a moot point, but I [still] think the instructor is forcing bad code. In [real world] practice, the first thing I'd do is change the prototype. IMO, it's the correct choice, except for the "artificial" restriction.

Comment: @Fe2O3 OP _did_ have a `printLL` function, called from `sortEmployee`. Hopefully, OP kept this (with some mods) to accomodate your indirect pointer array solution. [One of] the best sorts for a LL is mergesort. But, now that I think about it, although bubblesort is usually slow/bad, it does work well for doing a LL sort in-place.

Comment: @CraigEstey yeah, I always thought coding classes would be better with more independence in design, programming is an art, I would be almost tempted to merely dynamically copy a new list of linkages only, like new structs with only a next member, which were `malloc`ated and `memcpy`ied from the original list and then implement a `struct list` like one described, for bonus points or at least to give the professor my 2¢.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the list without modify the links one needs save the sort order to a separate array, this is untested but I believe it would be something like this:

```
bool containsEmpID(int empId, struct employee ** sorted, int count){
   int i = 0;
   bool found = false;
   while (i < count){
      if((*sorted)[i]->empId == empId){
         found = true;
         i = count;
      }
      i++;
   }
   return found;
}

void sortEmployee (struct employee * head){     // sorting function

    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Error!\n");
        return;
    }

    int count = 0;
    a3Emp * temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL){  
        temp = temp ->nextEmployee;              
        count++;
    }

    a3Emp * sorted[count];
    int sortedIndex = 0;

    a3Emp * current;
    sorted[0] = head; 
   

    while(sortedIndex < count) {

        current = head; 
        temp = current->nextEmployee;
            
        while(temp != NULL) {
            if(current->empId > temp->empId
               && !containsEmpID(temp->empId, sorted, sortedIndex+1) {
                current = temp;           
            }
            temp = temp->nextEmployee;
        }
        sorted[sortedIndex++] = current;
    }

    printf("Employees sorted by Employee Id: \n");
    printLL(sorted);

}
```

The `printLL` needs to be changed to `void printLL(struct employee ** sorted, int count)`, I assume this function is of one's making and can be changed as it is to be called within the sort function. One will need to then need to loop through the array and print each employee struct.

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate one solution to this problem:

```
// Abridged struct for this demo. Note use of "typedef"
typedef struct employee { 
    int empId;
    char *fname;
    struct employee *next;
} emp_t;

// A "generic" function to show the fields of a record
void printEmp( int n, emp_t *p ) {
    printf("\nEmployee #%d: \n", n + 1 );
    printf("\tEmployee id: %d\n", p->empId);
    printf("\tFirst Name: %s\n", p->fname);
}

// The LL approach separating "structure" from "data"
void printLL(emp_t *head) {
    for( int count = 0; head; head = head->next )
        printEmp( count++, head );
}

// qsort is lousy for small arrays, but it's reliable
int cmp( const void *a, const void *b ) {
    emp_t *pa = *(emp_t**)a, *pb = *(emp_t**)b;
    return pa->empId - pb->empId;
}

// Build an array of pointers from the LL, sort, display and discard.
void sortShow( emp_t *head ) {
    int i = 0;
    emp_t *p;

    for( p = head; p; p = p->next )
        i++;

    emp_t **arr = malloc( i * sizeof *arr ); // or a VLA if your compiler can...

    i = 0;
    for( p = head; p; p = p->next )
        arr[i++] = p;

    qsort( arr, i, sizeof arr[0], cmp );

    puts( "Now sorted by ID:" );
    for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        printEmp( j, arr[j] );

    free( arr );
}

int main( void ) {
    emp_t emps[] = { // hardwired abridged data to play with
        { 402, "Eugene" },
        { 809, "Sania" },
        { 106, "Andre" },
        { 100, "Roger" },
        { 524, "Johnny" },
    };
    const int nemps = sizeof emps/sizeof emps[0];

    for( int i = 1; i < nemps; i++ ) // connect up LL pointers
        emps[i-1].next = &emps[i];

    printLL( &emps[0] ); // As loaded

    sortShow( &emps[0] ); // sorted and printed

    return 0;
}
```

Little else to do today...